# Updating an OM cursor that went through a function

Tags: clojurescript, om

When calling `om/build`, one can send an `fn` option, which according to the documentation:

```
  `fn - a function to apply to x before invoking f.`
```

My question is, when applying `om/transact!` or `om/update!` to the cursor (x) that was manipulated by the `fn`, how does the original cursor get affected?

Answer (score 0):

`(om/build comp1 (f cursor))` has the same effect as `(om/build comp1 cursor {:fn f})`

So the answer is that it really depends what `f` does. As long as `(f x)` (or its content) is still a cursor, you can `om/transact!` or `om/update!` on it (or its content).

For example, if `x` is `{:x 1}` and `f` is `#(update-in % [:x] inc)`, `f` will apply on the **value** of the cursor; the underlying atom will not change. When you `om/transact!` or `om/update!` on `(f x)` it'll operate on the atom inside cursor `x`. On the next render, you'll once again get `(f x)` based on the updated `x`.

On the other hand, if `f` makes `x` not a cursor (e.g. `f` is `om/value`), then you won't be able to `om/transact!` or `om/update!` on it at all.

Hope that helps.